# Connect to a IIS with HTTPS and client-certificate authentication

Tags: java, c#, perl, iis, ssl-certificate

I really struggle with the following problem.
Must connect to a IIS with activated client-certificate-authentication and over https.

As far I think it is a pretty much MS story and therefore its a bit tough with other than MS-technologie

If I do in .net C# all is fine.

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest( WebRequest.Create ("https://abc.abc");
req.ClientCertificates.Add (new X509Certificate2 ("cert.pfx", "pwd"));
```

But I did not found any glue in doing it in Perl or Java. Just found username/passwort-authentication and SSL-certificates but I think thats something else here.

Here I get a HTTP 403.

Tried a lot of code (from axis to java ssl-context) but nothing was working properly.

But there must be a way because I can do it with a browser as well (add the certificate in the browsers store and it works).

Any help? 
Thanks!

Chris

Comment: In Perl you just give SSL_cert_file and SSL_key_file to the SSL options and it will use this as client certificates cert and key if the server requests a certificate. In other languages it is probably similar.

Comment: I tried that. But its not working. Get an http 500 error. But its the internal one (think its from LWP::Useragent). Do not know why its not able to connect if I user the ssl_cert_file and its able to connect (but gets the 403) if no ssl_cert_file.

Comment: Please provide code you used with LWP and the version of LWP. Make sure that you use at least version of LWP and that you use the default SSL backend IO::Socket::SSL. And please provide the details of the error you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the key. Perls LWP::Useragent needs also a key-file. But I need to add it not all within a PFX but all extra. If I did all was fine.
Thanks anyway!